# How can I practice my marksmanship for multiplayer?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I have a lot of trouble hitting things in Battlefront.

I think this is mostly due to how much time I've spent playing Call of Duty, which using line trace mechanics to determine whether you've hit something. In other words, there's no bullet drop and you don't have to lead targets.

It's also impacted by how much more accurate hip-fire seems to be than aimed fire at anything other than extreme distances, and my instinct to look down the sight whenever I'm shooting.

Additionally, the hip-fire reticles vary per gun, and none of them are crosshairs.

I'd like to practice shooting in a singleplayer mode where the enemies have the same health as they do in multiplayer. Is this possible? I tried playing a battle, but everything was going down in one or two hits.

Answer (score 4):

The higher the difficulty of the single player missions, the higher the health of the AI you are battling and the more accurate they are when shooting.
If you are playing as a hero you will do more damage, so make sure to be doing a normal battle and not a hero one.

Aiming down the sight does nothing to improve accuracy in Battlefront unfortunately, it merely gives more zoom. I have trouble remembering not to ADS, especially in close combat, but you'll find that the it will increase your performance dramatically (in close combat such as corridors on the Hoth levels).
I hate to admit it, but "spray and pray" could definitely be said to be a valid tactic in the close quarter combat in this game.

Comment: Do you on which difficulty, if any, the enemies have the same health as on multiplayer? I don't want to get used to shooting 4 shots and turning, only to find that it takes 5 against people. I can just try the highest of course, but shooting 5 when I only need 4 can be a problem as well.

Comment: @DCShannon Unfortunately no, I've only done the first two difficulties and they have been against a human opponent with AI turned on, so I was not concentrating on the AI as much. I would expect it is the highest difficulty though

Answer (score 2):

The way I practice is: Use the T-21b in any singleplayer battle (preferably Hoth) and attack any enemies at long range. Most of the battles don't have troops at the same HP as in multiplayer (unless you count Shock and Shadow troopers, and even then they have more HP), but this will improve twitch shooting and marksmanship.